# Does an In App Purchase's Product ID have to begin with a Reverse-DNS?

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

Does an In App Purchase's Product ID have to begin with a Reverse-DNS like `com.mycompany.My_Awesome_Game.Level_Pack_1` or can it just be standalone like `Level_Pack_1`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Product IDs can be whatever you want, although it is recomend you follow the reverse domain name style. But in the end there's no restriction over the naming of your product IDs. It also does not need to use your app bundle ID as a prefix.

From [the source](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1329/_index.html):

> Q: I am implementing In App Purchase
>   and must register my product
>   identifiers. What are product
>   identifiers and how do I create and
>   use them in my application?
>
> A: A product identifier is a string
>   used to uniquely identify every
>   product you wish to sell from your
>   application. The App Store uses it to
>   retrieve information about a product.
>   It is a string identifier that can
>   only contain alphanumeric
>   (A-Z,a-z,0-9), underscore (_), and
>   period (.) characters. You can use any
>   sequence of these characters for your
>   identifier. However, we recommend that
>   you use the reverse domain name style
>   (for example,
>   com.companyname.application.productid)
>   when creating your identifier.

So 'Level_Pack_1' —as in your example— would be a valid product id.

Comment: Not a good practice to recommend.  There's not enough namespace in the App store database otherwise.

Comment: @hotpaw2: Apple never states that product IDs live in a global namespace; it seems unlikely that they do. (Doing so would be poor architecture on their part and would probably warrant bigger warning signs about uniqueness.)

Comment: what is the product id for ios please help me , is the reference name or what ? I also get empty list

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question but I'm directed here since recently I've been wondering about the same question. Eventually as I walked through the implementation of IAP in my project this has become clear to me:

1. if you don't need App Store to host content for your In-App Purchase the Product ID can be any combination of Alphanumeric (A-Za-z0-9), underscore (_) and dot (.);
2. if you do need App Store to host content the Product ID must be reverse-DNS like (*com.yourCompany.yourProduct*) and must match the bundle identifier of your In-App Purchase Content project. Later when you archive the content project and upload it with Xcode archive uploader this is how App Store Connect knows how to associate the uploaded content with the in-app purchase product.

Answer (score -1):

i have encountered "no in-app products received (0)" for many months tried to solve this problem. the result:

credits_1 was not allowed, but credits1 is working fine! so, don't use any _- symbols