# Is it possible to get the In App Purchase Product identifiers list based on bundle identifier of the application

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I want to do a sample application. In which i have to display the `In App Purchase product identifiers` list based on the `bundle identifier` of the application. Is it possible to get the `product identifiers` list?. If it is possible please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Apple does not provide a method to get all the inapp products available for an app. They have mentioned this in their documentation. Either we should hard code this in our app or use a separate API call to return the list of products.

**Idea about My One of Implementation**

**Product-Identifier = Bundle-Identifier + Meaning full name of Product**

Keep all the Product identifier in .Plist or at some convenient place from where you can easily change.

Or

One of dynamic approach is user server model. In short retrieve product list from your server through web-service.

I have created helper class that give me product identifier list here .I get product name form database and crate productidentifier by appending product name with bundleidentifier.you may get your product name form .plist and create productidentifier by appending productname with bundle identifier

```
+ (SPAppPurchaseHelper *)sharedInstance {
  static dispatch_once_t once;
  static SPAppPurchaseHelper * sharedInstance;
  dispatch_once(&once, ^{
      FMDBHandler *dbHandler= [[FMDBHandler alloc] init];
     NSString *query=@"SELECT productId FROM PlayList";
    NSArray *tblDataArr= [dbHandler getListBySQL:query];
    NSString *bundleIdentifier = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
    NSMutableArray *identifierArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for(NSMutableDictionary *productDict in tblDataArr){

        NSString *productIdetifierStr= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@",bundleIdentifier,[productDict objectForKey:@"productId"]];
        [identifierArray addObject:productIdetifierStr];
    }

    NSSet * productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithArray:identifierArray];
    sharedInstance = [[self alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
});
return sharedInstance;
}
```

Comment: is it necessary to add bundle identifier in product identifier? @user1548843

Comment: Hey,@YogendraPatel sorry bit late in reply. It's not necessary to add bundle identifier in product identifier but it should be uniq and only use A-Z,a-z or underscore and period (.) for name.but it is recommended that we use reverse domain name style. please find this link may help to get your answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605609/does-an-in-app-purchases-product-id-have-to-begin-with-a-reverse-dns